# NHibernate: Converting an IQUERY to a dataset?

Tags: nhibernate, dataset

Is it possible to convert an IQuery that is returned from Nhibernate to a dataset?

I have managed to get the data to an ILIST (collection of hashtables) but how do i get it converted into a dataset?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/05/09/Converting-an-object-collection-to-a-DataSet.aspx) on google, check all the code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("CustomerId", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("CustomerName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("RegisteredAt", typeof(string));//not a typo, sadly.

// ... lot more properties, often nested ones.

foreach(Customer cust in customers)
{
  DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
  row["CustomerId"] = cust.Id;
  row["CustomerName"] = cust.At(reportDate).Name;
  row["RegisteredAt"] = cust.RegisteredAt.ToShortDateString();
  //... lot more properties

  dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
return ds;
```